# Repeat sql request for different criteria and export excel file at each time

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, extract, automated-builds

I have a database with data from 2017 to 2019 of different sites (like different cities). I want to extract one table excel for data of one site in one year, for example site A in 2017, site A in 2018, site A in 2019 then site B in 2017, .... I want to use each file for an analyse with python later. Is there a way to automate the request to do this ? I have almost 10000 sites so I want to have then 10000*3 excel files, and it take a lot of time to change critera of "where" at each time. If it is possible to automate this process, I can then launch it at night.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Hi, I think we need more context here. What you propose is totally doable and seeing you talk about Python makes me think you already know the primary tools... so the problem becomes understanding what is preventing you from automating this. What do you launch at night? How do you connect to the database? Is this analysis done through some 3rd party tool?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. In fact I have a database with incoming and outcoming flow in each store (site) from years. I have already a Python code to analyse data of each store in one year (from an excel file) and I want to apply this analyse to all the sites in the database from 2017 to 2019. I think I can automate the Python process when I have all the excel files ready, I want to automate the extract process then that I can obtain all of my 10000*3 excel file without modifying at each time the site and year criteria.

Comment: For the moment the sql extracting process is not yet connected to the python process. I did it separately. I don't know if there is a way to connect it or not. The database is on Oracle and I did my Python process with spyder/jupiter notebook

Comment: It seems that the key is to understand how do you extract the Excel file. Do you produce it through some UI? Do you connect via SSH and launch some command?

Comment: I don't really know what is UI or SSH. In fact, I have connections to the database (with multiple tables, I use oracle sql developer) and then I launch my query (like select ... from ... where). Once the data is extracted, I ask to extract the output as an excel file. I think that what I'm doing with sql is really basic so it may be difficult to automate the process.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/) Exporting data to Excel is typically a feature of the SQL _client_ you are using, not the database server. So we also need to know which SQL tool you use to access the database

Comment: So, if I understand this right, your database is Oracle and you are using Oracle's Sql Developer to extract the data into Excel files by clicking on some buttons and saving the file. Do I understand correctly? (side-note: UI stands for User Interface and is a generic term to indicate anything that you use to interface yourself with the computer, although usually it's referred to some kind of graphical interface with buttons, lists and the likes)

Comment: exactly, so then what I really looking for is to have access to the database since a python console. I tried using cx_Oracle like this 

con = cx_Oracle.connect('Username/Password@linktoserver') but I have always a message like ORA-12154: TNS : l'identificateur de connexion indiqué n'a pas pu être résolu. I worked with Oracle SQL developer.

Comment: Finally i found a solution for my question in this link (https://datatofish.com/how-to-connect-python-to-an-oracle-database-using-cx_oracle/). I can now connect to my database in Oracle since Python then I can change my SQL queries by using a loop. I obtain the result of the queries in type of tuple for each row and then I think I can save and convert it into pandas dataframe then apply the next step of my analysis.